# Calling subclass method from superclass BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, broadcastreceiver

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with a problem I'm having in an android app. I have several subclasses that extend a superclass. This superclass contains a (local) BroadcastReceiver. The reason I put the receiver in the superclass is because I'd like each subclass to listen for the same broadcast. However, once that broadcast comes in, I'd like each subclass to do something completely different.

What's the best way to approach this? I initially created a new receiver inside each subclass but I feel like there's probably a better way to do this. This is the most basic example of what my superclass would look like:

```
public class SuperClassService extends Service{

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mReceiver, new IntentFilter("BROADCAST_RECEIVED"));
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       // Unregister since the activity is paused.
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
            mReceiver);
       super.onPause();
   }

   private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // do something in subclass ......
       }
   };
}
```

Every subclass simply extends this. So what's the best practice on getting something in the subclass called when the superclass onReceive gets triggered through a broadcast? Again, my subclasses will be doing different things so I don't think placing a common method in the superclass is the way to go. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't see the problem with creating a method common to all of the subclasses (by putting it in the superclass) and simply overriding the method in each of the subclasses?

Comment: Have an abstract `doSomething` method in superclass that is called from your Receiver and have each subclass overwrite it with its own action.